# WinRm: remove IPs from listeningOn

Tags: networking, winrm

- My machine is a Windows 10 Pro x64 @1804 (is not a server, so I posted here and not on ServerFault)
- My **final** goal is enable this machine to be remote controlled using `ansible`, but only by a specific LAN address. **This question is *not* about the ip to which I am opened; I ask you how to remove some IPs on which I'm listening on;** these IPs are coming from virtual network interfaces like (VmWare + Vbox + Hyper-V)

I enumerated active listeners

```
winrm enumerate winrm/config/Listener
```

I got, with other infos, this row:

```
 ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.10, 192.168.56.1, 192.168.203.1,
               192.168.231.1, ::1, 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:1c43:1cb1:a8ed:c186,
               fe80::40:a36c:364a:53df%30, fe80::1c43:1cb1:a8ed:c186%13, 
               fe80::406b:b429:4b90:4acf%36, fe80::84c0:e900:ce4e:dead%35
```

I would like to remove some IPs, because are transient, due to virtualizations testes

I found another question here on SuperUser, but has no answers: [Restrict WinRM communication to specific server](https://superuser.com/questions/772686/restrict-winrm-communication-to-specific-server)

So, the question is: how to remove IPs from `ListeningOn` ?

Thanks in advance, and *feel free to edit question or tags to be more clear.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run cmd.exe as administrator and try the following command:

```
WinRM Delete WinRM/Config/Listener?Address=IP:x.x.x.x+Transport=HTTP
```

You could need to pay attention to the capitalization of words, if it tells you unknow operation.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: If the above command does not work for you, you can delete the listener entirely with `winrm delete winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP` and recreate it according to your needs afterwards.